# Stuck in read() call

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple client-server app using sockets in C, however I encounter an issue: sometimes the client is stuck in the reading process from the server.
I checked and the string is send to the client but the client never receives it. I say sometimes because this doesn't happen every time and I can't find what is causing the issue. To be more detailed the client receives a string from the server (the question) and sends back the answer. After some repeats (the server needs to send any number of questions) of the this process the client just stops reading the question, but from the server side the question is send.
This is where the client does the reading part.

```
  while (1)
  {
    char question[200] = "";
    printf("Receiving...\n");
    if ((read(sd, question, sizeof(question))) < 0)
    {
      perror("Error receiving question\n");
      return errno;
    }
    question[strlen(question)] = '\0';
    printf("Question: %s\n", question);

    if (writeAnswer(sd) == 0)
      break;
    getFeedback(sd);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This is where the server is sending the question:

```
  if ((write(client, question, strlen(question))) < 0)
  {
    perror("Error sending the question\n");
    return errno;
  }
  else
    printf("Question successfully sent:%s\n", question);
  return 1;
```

Comment: `question[strlen(question)] = '\0';` If the string already has a `\0` then this is pointless. If it does not, this might not work - who knows if there is a 0 anywhere in the buffer. Instead, use the number of bytes returned from `read()`

Comment: Also, there is no guarantee the entire message will be consumed in one call to `read()`. Read in a loop until you have all bytes. This may require sending a terminating character in the string.

Comment: You need to examine the return-value of the recv() call to know how many bytes of valid data have been written into your buffer… it’s not guaranteed to be the number you passed in as an argument (it won’t be more, but it often will be less)

Comment: The same applies to the `write` call. It may accept only a part of your data and you would have to call it again with the next part.

Comment: Can you clarify the socket type/protocol being used?  I presume it's SOCK_STREAM(tcp) rather than SOCK_DGRAM(udp) or something else.

Comment: I tried doing that but the nothing gets pass the read() part so I can't get the return value from read

Comment: @G.M. yes, the socket type is TCP

Comment: I tried now and if I only read the first few characters from the question this doesn't happen, so I think the socket can receive only a certain amount of data.